# How to set BaseBTreeFolder object's name?

Tags: python, plone

I created this object which inherits from `plone.app.folder.base.BaseBTreeFolder`. After creating it, Plone sets a long name which contains the object name and creation date to it. How can I change the name to the same as title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your type with the factory tool.

When so registered content is created initially inside a sandbox, just so you can fill out the edit form for the first time. Once you submit the edit form, the item is created for real and is given an id based on the title.

To register, either manually enable your type on the "Factory Types" tab of the `portal_factory` object (in the ZMI), or register your type in your GenericSetup profile with a file named `factorytool.xml` containing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_factory">
 <factorytypes>
  <type portal_type="YourTypeName" />
 <factorytypes>
</object>
```

You also need to make sure your type has the rename flag set to True; in your class definition add:

```
_at_rename_after_creation = True
```

Comment: I did this, but it does not work. Maybe I did not clearly explain my problem. It is not the name one can see in its parent folder, it is the url of the object. For example, I created this object and set the title to `test`, I can see its name `test` in the parent folder, but the url is `objectname.2012-10-17.2203112108` which I want it to be `test` as well.

Comment: @tman: Yeah, that's what I understood. The id of the object (which is what is used in the URL). Expanded.

Comment: @Martjin You are genius man. You saved my day again. I never knew there was such flag. Thanks.